# How best to bulk/merge together objects in an arraylist which are related/similar but not identical in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, merge

I am receiving an arrayList of objects which have various payment totals. Some payments are related by a reference number, currency and dates, the total number may be different.

I am required to bulk/merge together objects which are related but are not all identical due to payment totals.

How do I best filter through to find related objects and add together the payment totals to form one record.

```
[{'ref':'JK88', 'paydate':'22092020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '2000'},
{'ref':'PY99', 'paydate':'03072020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '4558'},
{'ref':'FK33', 'paydate':'05032020', 'CUR':'JPY', 'payment': '2500'},
{'ref':'JK88', 'paydate':'22092020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '7609'},
{'ref':'JK88', 'paydate':'22092020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '4822'},
{'ref':'JK88', 'paydate':'22092020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '430933'}]
```

All objects with the same ref, date and currency together are unique and should have payment total added together, 
so the outcome would be :

```
[{'ref':'JK88', 'paydate':'22092020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '57524'},
{'ref':'PY99', 'paydate':'03072020', 'CUR':'EUR', 'payment': '4558'},
{'ref':'FK33', 'paydate':'05032020', 'CUR':'JPY', 'payment': '2500'}]
```

Comment: I would create a map, and use the ref, data, and currency as key.  You can then iterate through the list of items - if an item does not exist in the map, add it.  If it does exist, update the total.

Comment: Well, you basically already wrote what you'd have to do: collect all objects with the same ref, date and currency (would be some form of composite key) and sum their payments. Then you use that data to create new objects with the same key and a payment value that equals the sum of the others.

Comment: What you have here looks like a _JSON_ array - do you really mean Java or rather JavaScript?

Comment: @Thomas Ah sorry I meant to add that I received it as a JSON object but I use an ObjectMapper() to read the values and convert to arraylist of the 'payment' object